# IComparable comparision

Tags: c#

```
if ((key == null && group.Key == null) || (key is DBNull && group.Key is DBNull) ||
                    (!(key is IComparable) && !(group.Key is IComparable)))
```

Can the above code simplified like below,

```
if(key == group.key || (!(key is IComparable) && !(group.Key is IComparable)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not unless you restrict what values the variables can have, or what type they are declared as.

If for example `key` is an `int` with the value `4` and `group.Key` is an `int` with the value `4`, the first code gives `false` while the second code gives `true`.